Using a single port for either a battery or external power supply
I have a circuit that can be powered by either USB-C, a LiPo battery or an external power supply. Because of a small footprint I would like the battery and external power supply (5-18V) to share the same 2-pin port.
I'm looking for a way to:

charge the battery if USB-power is present
use the battery as power input if no USB-power is present
use the external power supply when connected and the USB port only for communication
have 3.3V, 5V and the external power supply voltage accessible in the circuit

I have trouble finding a single IC, so was thinking to watch the voltage on the connector and depending if the voltage is <5V switch the charger off.
Is there any IC or reference circuit anyone is aware of that could suit the application?

I think the would be best if you use 2 "or" ICs like TPS2412 or similar to be able to have both external and USB power connected at the same time. Use 2 of them, one for each source, connecting each power supply to input of obe of them and connect outputs together. If this is done correctly, the circuit will automatically have one or the other selected. The output of this circuit can then be used as a source for appropriate battery charger IC, there are loads out there and the choice depends on current, feature that are required like temp sensor controls etc and communication if needed (i2c,..).
If you want to charge the battery only from usb, use tps2412 or similar after battery charger, so one input is battery voltage and the other external voltage.

Thank you for the comment. I was hoping to connect both battery and external power source to a single port "VIN" and based on the measured voltage either charge the battery or draw from the battery/ other power source.
